# Removing a fragment in another fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that implements an `onClickListener`, and then the `onClickListener` tries to remove a fragment.

I get a red line under `badFragment` in `transaction.remove(badFragment);`. My best guess is because it can't tell what that fragment is/where it is.

How would I go about finding that fragment, so that it can be removed?

I've tried findFragmentId(badFragment); but it doesn't work.

*Bonus points if you can let me know where you found this method. As I'm not great at looking up things in the Android Docs.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find fragment

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

or

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
```

you can remove fragment itself

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I never defined badFragment... silly me. `Bad_fragment badFragment = new Bad_fragment();` Thanks for the response though!

Comment: And for the bonus points: [`findFragmentById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)) + [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove(android.app.Fragment)).